# How can i get rid of the exception 'The RPC server is unavailable' while saving the Outlook message via python?

Tags: python, outlook, rpc, win32com, com-automation

I'm working with win32com library and try to save mail i've just created.
I use .CreateItem() function to create mail instance and try to save it using `mail.Save()`
Unfortunately i get this exception `(-2147023174, 'The RPC server is unavailable.', None, None)`. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Perhaps show a bit more of your code? If you have created an ‘Outlook.Application’ object via Dispatch(), it should stick around until it goes out of scope: at that point IDispatch.Release() is called, and the COM system knows you are done with the application.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't show you code. I create 'Outlook.Application' obect via `win32com.client.gencanche.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")`. Outlook object does not go out of scope while app is running. First answer helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the Outlook.exe process has finished its work and gone. Check out the list of running processes when you got this kind of errors.

You may try to get an instance of the Explorer window to stop Outlook from closing by using `Explorers.Add` method which creates a new instance of the explorer window.

```
Sub DisplayDrafts()  
 Dim myExplorers As Outlook.Explorers  
 Dim myOlExpl As Outlook.Explorer  
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder  
 
 Set myExplorers = Application.Explorers  
 Set myFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)  
 Set myOlExpl = myExplorers.Add(myFolder, olFolderDisplayNoNavigation)  
' myOlExpl.Display  
End Sub
```